# Monitoring newly or updated events in HPSM 9.20 Web Services

Tags: java

I am new to HPSM 9.20 WebServices.Can anyone let me know how to get new or updated events in HPSM. Also let me know how to monitor the events in HPSM 9.20

Answer (score 1):

There are four ways that you could get incidents into HPSM.

SCAuto SDK - An old C based Sockets application that you can send incidents to and they translate into event records

Connect-It - HP's integration software for HPSM.  Basically its drag and drop mapping with the ability to do some scripting in Cypress Basic.

Text Import (i.e. CSV) - You could potentially import the csv of data by going to database manager and then choosing Import Text Wizard from the drop down menu on the right (below Import Unload file)

The JavaScript Library - You could write a JavaScript routine to go grab files and/or information and then schedule that script to occur on a regular basis.

or Web Services like you mentioned.....

You can use Web Services to send requests to HP Service Manager.

http://hpsmservername:13080/sc62server/PWS/IncidentManagement.wsdl
http://hpsmservername:13080/SM/7/IncidentManagement?wsdl

This help guide on Web Services might help
http://smnsn2cm.saas.hp.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/tailor/web_services/concepts/web_services.htm